# Git : find all commits that modify a file that are not related to my commit and another one

Tags: git, git-log

I want to know if there are any commits elsewhere unrelated to mine that modify files of a given folder, that I might be interested in. I also want to exclude revisions that are ancestors of another known commit.

For one revision, I think it's pretty easy, I can do :

```
git log --all <rev1>.. <folder>
```

But how to exclude another revision ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add --not and your branch name to exclude it from being shown :

> git log --all < rev1>.. --not <known_commit> -- < folder >

Comment: One thing to notice about using `--not` is that it is order sensitive, e.g. `--all --not x` is not the same as `--not x --all`.

Comment: @Mohamed amine ben hassen Oh this really great ! Spot on !

Comment: @hlovdal Care to expand ? Seems important.

Comment: From [git-rev-list manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list): "--not Reverses the meaning of the ^ prefix (or lack thereof) **for all following revision specifiers**, up to the next --not".

Comment: Does this still hold for `log` though ? Does `log` inherit that as a porcelain command from the `rev-list` command which is plumbing ?

Comment: @Charles yes, `git log` parses revisions the same way that `git rev-list` does. Both use the same parsing mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably clearer to not use the range syntax at all, but to [exclude the commits](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_commit_exclusions) explicitly:

```
git log --all ^rev1 ^rev2 -- <folder>
```

`^rev` excludes all commits reachable from rev1 (including rev1). In other words `rev1..rev2` as dotted range notation is equivalent to `^rev1 rev2`.

Comment: I think this is the same idea as what I marked as an answer, but with a different syntax (`--not rev1 rev2` instead of `^rev1 ^rev2`)

Comment: @Charles yes, it is similar. But it does _not_ use the range syntax (`rev1.. ^rev2`), but instead uses the exclude notation exclusively (`^rev1 ^rev2`). The difference is not in `^rev2` vs `--not rev2`, but in `--all rev1..` vs `--all ^rev1`

Comment: Well, put it this way. There are 4 solutions : `rev1.. --not rev2`, `rev1.. ^rev2`, `--not rev1 rev2` and `^rev1 ^rev2`.

Comment: @Charles yes, exactly. I find it clearer to either use dotted range syntax or single commits (with exclusion syntax), but not mix both notations in a single command.